# How to pass Accept: application json header in call, post request Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.1

How do I pass the "Accept: application/json" in request when testing:

for eg:

```
$response = $this->post($route, $data, ['Accept: application/json']);
```

OR

```
$response = $this->call('post' $route, $data, [], [], ['Accept: application/json']);
```

I want to invoke `$this->wantsJson()` in the FormRequest class:

```
/**
     * Get the proper failed validation response for the request.
     *
     * @param  array  $errors
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function response(array $errors)
    {
        if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson()) {
            return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
        }

        return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                                        ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
                                        ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$this->json()`.

> Visit the given URI with a JSON request.

Here's a link from Laravel's API:

[Laravel 5.1 API](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.html#method_json)

[Laravel 5.2 API](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.html#method_json)

Edit: For Laravel 7, you can visit their docs for [Testing JSON APIs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests#testing-json-apis).

Comment: is this available in 5.1?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova - Links are no longer valid. Any for Laravel 7 or upcoming 8?

Comment: @s3c Updated my answer with their docs for Laravel 7 & posting json to a route and it is the same for Laravel 8. (Also it's no longer upcoming, as it was released yesterday AFAIK). :)

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Yes, it was released sometime between my comment and two hours later. I wanted to say it just came out, but I'd be lying at that point in time. Thank you for the link. BTW, the two links for Laravel 5 are still **dead** so you might as well remove them if not find working ones. Upvoted.